# Incompatible type error between scanner.next() and String

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, incompatibletypeerror

I am trying to compile this block of code, and it is telling me that `in.next()` in the while loop is not compatible with `String`, but I thought the `next()` method returns a `String`?

I have import statements for `Scanner` class and `java.io`

```
public static void main ( String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
    while ( in.hasNext()){
        in = stringReverse(in.next());
    }
}

public static String stringReverse ( String s ) {...}
```

Comment: The error is because you're assigning a `String` to `in`, which is of type `Scanner`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `stringReverse` returns a `String` which is incompatible with `in` which is of type `Scanner`

Answer (score 0):

```
in = stringReverse(in.next());
```

`Scanner#next()` returns a String, which is passed to `stringReverse()`, which returns a String. You attempt to save that String in `in`, which points to a Scanner object.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong reference for assigning the String type.
Please see the correct code below. Hope this helps

```
    public static void main ( String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        String assignStringHere = "";
        while ( in.hasNext()){
            assigneStringHere = stringReverse(in.next());
        //in ----> is not an object of String class, rather its an object of Scanner class 
        //Thats the reason you are getitng the erro.
        }
    }
```